# text label is not a member of 'Ui::Dialog' Qt

Tags: image, qt, dialog, label

I am attempting to place an image in a label in my openCV code. The opencv part works swimmingly. However, displaying the Qimage is proving to be a problem. I am placing the image in the label as such.

ui->lblOriginal->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));

However, it is telling me that "error: C2039: 'lblOriginal' : is not a member of 'Ui::Dialog'"

lblOriginal is a label in my dialog. Is there something I am missing? This is the entire code in dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    capWebcam.open(0);

    tmrTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(tmrTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processAndUpdateGUI()));
    tmrTimer->start(20);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::processAndUpdateGUI(){
    capWebcam >> matOriginal;

    if(matOriginal.empty() == true)return;

    cv::cvtColor(matOriginal,matOriginal, CV_BGR2RGB);

    QImage qimgOriginal((uchar*)matOriginal.data, matOriginal.cols, matOriginal.rows,matOriginal.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);

    ui->lblOriginal->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));

}
```

The us xml file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1181</width>
    <height>590</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="lblOrignal">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>80</x>
     <y>36</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>480</height>
    </rect>
    </property>
   <property name="autoFillBackground">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>TextLabel</string>
  </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Could you post your xml ui file?

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are making a basic mistake, in your UI fle you have:

```
<widget class="QLabel" name="lblOrignal">
```

and your trying to reference as:

```
ui->lblOriginal->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));
```

So have you checked the difference ? if not lblOrignal is not equals to lblOriginal.

Comment: GAAAAAAH TYPOS!!!! Thank you so much for noticing that. I feel pretty silly now for not noticing it myself.

Comment: if compiler says that it doesn't exist, it means that it doesn't exist  ;). Please **check** an answer if it solved your question @user2442449.